Understanding field lines of uniformly moving charging
Here you can simulate a moving point charge's field lines. I cannot conceptualise why uniformly moving charges do not create breaks in the field lines.
As I see it, the information of a charge having moved the amount $ds = vt$, for ($v << c$), propagates with light speed.
Let the charge propagate on the line: $s(t) = p_{start} + vt$

So for a point in space and time $(x,y,z,t)$, how do I calculate the direction the electric field is pointing too? (How do I describe mathematically where the E-field is pointing to?)
How can I understand that thus it looks like the field lines change infinitely fast through space and time. (They seem like they do, but they certainly cannot)

Now consider $v$ close to $c$.
A similar effect to the aberration of light should apply here. But also does not make much sense too me. Obviously the field behind should also see the changes of the moving charge.
Maybe somebody can help creating a mental model.

You can find the relevant calculations in this PDF.

How can I understand that thus it looks like the field lines change infinitely fast through space and time. The field changes have had time to propagate at $c$ from where the charge was in the past. To understand this better, consider the field of an arbitrarily moving charge, which involves the “retarded time”.

I cannot conceptualise why uniformly moving charges do not create breaks in the field lines. Why would uniform motion cause a break? In uniform motion every instant is just like every other instant. A break is when something is not like it was.

Most electromagnetism texts give the equation,
${\bf E}= \frac{q{\bf r}}
{\gamma^2[r^2-({\bf v\times r})^2]^{\frac{3}{2}}}$,
for the field of uniformly moving charge.
The field lines are straight lines.
Where does all the complication come from?
